# Where does this inequality come from for $e^{-2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One of the proofs in my textbook has the following step involving an inequality for $e^{-2}$:

$$
\left(1 - \frac1{d+1} \right)^{2d} \ge \frac1{e^2}
$$

Where does this come from?

Comment: Do you know the limit of $(1 - \frac{1}{d})^{2d}$ of $d \to \infty$? Some basic manipulations of that will do the trick.

Comment: @TMM so lim of $\left(1 - \frac1d\right)^{2d}$ is like $\left(1 - \frac1\infty \right)^{2\infty}$, which equals $\left(1 - 0\right)^\infty$, which seems to equal 1, but that's not what i get when i graph it out... what am i missing?

Comment: $1^\infty$ is like $\infty/\infty$, you *can't conclude* the exact limit only from that. Now its limit is, surprisingly $e^{-2}$.

Comment: It should help a bit to write the parenthesis as a single fraction, then invert the sides of the inequality, leading to $(1+1/d)^{2d}\le e^2$. Take the logarithm of that, and you're perhaps in more familiar territory. (Hint: The graph of the logarithm lies below its tangent at $1$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual everything follows from $e^x \geq 1+x$.

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 + \frac{x}{n} > 0$ this inequality leads to

$$
e^x = e^{\frac{x}{n} \cdot n} \geq \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n
$$

and taking reciprocals

$$
e^{-x} \leq \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^{-n} = \left(1 - \frac{x}{n + x}\right)^n.
$$

Take $x=1$ to get

$$ \frac{1}{e} \leq \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n
$$

and therefore

$$ \frac{1}{e^2} \leq \left(1 - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2n}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You have to know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$
Then you can manipulate your expression and find

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2n} = \underbrace{\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{-(n+1)}\right)^{-(n+1)}\right]^{-2}}_{\to\frac{1}{e^2}\;\text{as $n$ increases}}\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{-(n+1)}\right)^{-2}}_{\to1\;\text{as $n$ increases}}$$

The limit to $n\to\infty$ of the first underbraced term is $e^{-2}$ and the limit of the second right-hand term is 1. Since the left-hand side term is monotically decreasing, you know that

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2n} \geq \frac{1}{e^2}$$

Comment: That doesn't work -- the second factor goes to $1$ for $n\to\infty$, so the product on the right-hand side goes to $\mathrm e^{-2}$, and you haven't provided any argument why it should stay above that limit.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Should have used the fact that the function is monotically decreasing to $\frac{1}{e^2}$.